# Cat sporadically sratches and pees at the same time

Tags: cats

Lately my girl cat all of sudden goes nuts on reaching at her backside to scratch and bite and starts peeing as if she's lost bladder control. It seems unintentional, like she doesn't realize she's doing it because she's so engrossed in getting at this all of a sudden itch.

What could be happening?

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of things that could be causing this:

- If your cat is older, she could have kidney or bladder problems making the area irritated.
- If she's older, she could be having difficulties with fleas.
- If she's had recent problems with diarrhea or not eating, she could have blocked scent glands (trust me, this is a vet problem. You do NOT want to try to clear them yourself).

You need to take her to a vet and get her checked out: fleas are easily dealt with but the other possible causes of her irritation back there need a professional.